# how to use url routing in codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

please suggest me url routing in codigniter.

i have a directory in my views folder name is   admin

in url routing file i write

```
    $route['admin'] = "admin/login";
```

and second i have dynamic url with category name like

like www.exapmple.com/categoryname/pagename

for this i will wite code in my route file

```
 $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Post/postdata/$1/$2';
```

but after this

i will not able go to admin page please suggest me something

Comment: Please check my answer, it will helpful to resolve your issue. Let me know if issue still persist.

Comment: Try swapping the order of your 2 routes.

Comment: please give me example in my rout file my routs are route['admin(:any)'] = "admin/login"; $route['(:any)'] = "Page/pagedata/$1"; $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Post/postdata/$1/$2'; but not working suggest me

Comment: @hardythoe did you load URL helper?

Answer (score 2):

In your routes config, put `$route['admin'] = "admin/login";` before `$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Post/postdata/$1/$2';`

As per [Codeigniter's official documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html),

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Comment: my routs are route['admin(:any)'] = "admin/login"; $route['(:any)'] = "Page/pagedata/$1"; $route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'Post/postdata/$1/$2'; but not working

Comment: You missed the `/`. Try replacing `route['admin(:any)'] = "admin/login";` with `route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/login";`